# Only document.ready code runs on page reload in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm using [this tutorial](http://blog.seancarpenter.net/2012/11/05/page-specific-javascript-with-the-asset-pipeline/) to load page specific JavaScript in my Rails app. My file structure looks like this:

```
app/assets/javascripts/
├── application.js
├── charts.coffee
├── dashboard
│   └── settings.js
├── dashboard-bundle.js
└── static_pages.coffee
```

I precompile my assets with `config.assets.precompile += %w( *-bundle.js )` and the file `dashboard-bundle.js` simply includes the line `//= require_tree ./dashboard/`. Then, on my page where I want to JavaScript to be loaded, I include the JavaScript with `= javascript_include_tag 'dashboard-bundle'`.

Here's a sample of what part of my `settings.js` file looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('Page and Javascript loaded!');
});
$('#renderChart1').click(function() {
  alert('You want to edit options for chart1!');
});
```

When I first load the page from another page, both alerts appear at the appropriate time; the first on page load and the second when I click the `#renderChart1` button.

However, when I reload the page without going to another page first, only the first alert works correctly. When clicking on the button, the alert does not appear.

I've already tried installing [jQuery Turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `#renderChart1` was added to DOM after binding `.click()` method for it, and you should move to `document.ready` to make sure that element was loaded into DOM, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('Page and Javascript loaded!');
  $('#renderChart1').click(function() {
    alert('You want to edit options for chart1!');
  });
});
```